# .Net Core 2. How to upload a file with metadata in same request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to upload a file to a .net core 2 rest API while in the same POST request also upload metadata (which will be stored in database). By metadata I mean a few info about the file (uploader, date/time of upload and just a few more) as Json format.

I have searched and tried different ways found on Stackoverflow but none worked. I am right now at this point.

The API Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> upload(IFormFile file, MyMetadata metadata)
    {
        // my logic
    }
```

The client:

```
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var multiPartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                multiPartFormDataContent.Add
                    (
                        new StreamContent(fileStream)
                        {
                            Headers =
                            {
                                ContentLength = fileStream.Length,
                                ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")
                            }
                        }
                        , "file"
                        , Path.GetFileName(filePath)
                    );

                var link = /mycontroller/upload;

                var resultTask = client.PostAsync(link, multiPartFormDataContent);

                var result = await resultTask;
```

I have tried adding the model to multPartFormDataContent but without success.

So what I am asking for, is a complete solution Controller and Client in same answer that will work.

Comment: If metadata is text and not too big, you could add it to the request header and parse it on the server.

Comment: I have edited the post. Metadata is just a json (serialized and deserialized from) with some information about the file.